# How to do parallel processing for post processing steps in IBM OPL?

Tags: optimization, opl

I am working on reducing the time for my optimization problem in IBM OPL tool. Post processing after the model run is taking the most of the time. Is there any way to do a parallel processing for the independent blocks of post processing?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do parallelism directly in OPL scripting.

There are two alternatives:

1. Just dump the result to disk (or database) and then create an external program that does the post processing and is parallelized.
2. Use [IloOplCallJava()](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.10.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/refjsopl/html/OPL_functions.html#IloOplCallJava) to create new threads/processes in Java that could potentially be parallelized.

If you give some more details about what exactly your post processing is and what the time consuming aspects are then we may find more ideas how to speed things up.